# Async.io as_completed returns ClientResponse coroutine instead of actual response with content

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency, python-asyncio

I'm making concurrent web requests to URL and i'm using asyncio.as_completed() function to get the response but when i try to print the response.it is giving coroutine expression and not the actual response values.

sharing the code below for reference

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch_status(session: ClientSession, url: str) -> int:
    async with session.get(url) as result:
        return result
    
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        fetchers = [fetch_status(session, 'https://www.example.com'),
                    fetch_status(session, 'https://www.example.com'),
                    fetch_status(session, 'https://www.example.com')]
 
        for finished_task in asyncio.as_completed(fetchers):
            print(await finished_task)
```

Response:

```
<coroutine object as_completed.<locals>.wait_for_one at 0x938742>
ClientResponse(...)[200 OK]
<CIMultiDictProxy>('Content-Type':'application/json', 'Content-Length':'803',.....)
```

Tried multiple ways but throwing **coroutine is not iterable**.could you please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: As explained in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed), you need to `await` the coroutines that are returned from `as_completed()`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in the code, Please check the edit. i'm actually doing await  and then trying to print the response

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Your code is not correct as I get `create_task() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` when running it.

Comment: @FiddleStix , Please check the edit for the working code.I have provided reproducible example and also pls remove downvote since i have rectified the mistake.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have:

```py
async def fetch_status(session: ClientSession, url: str) -> int:
    async with session.get(url) as result:
        return result
```

But if your intention is to return the response from the `session.get` call, do not use it as a context manager:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch_status(session: ClientSession, url: str) -> int:
    return await session.get(url)

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        fetchers = [fetch_status(session, 'https://www.example.com'),
                    fetch_status(session, 'https://www.example.com'),
                    fetch_status(session, 'https://www.example.com')]

        for finished_task in asyncio.as_completed(fetchers):
            response = await finished_task
            print(response)
            print(await response.text())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Simpler is to just do:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        fetchers = [session.get('https://www.example.com'),
                    session.get('https://www.example.com'),
                    session.get('https://www.example.com')]

        for finished_task in asyncio.as_completed(fetchers):
            response = await finished_task
            print(response)
            # Actual content:
            print(await response.text())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

**Update**

If I comment out printing the returned content and only print the response, I get:

```None
<ClientResponse(https://www.example.com) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Age': '592259', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=604800', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Date': 'Mon, 10 Jul 2023 17:05:53 GMT', 'Etag': '"3147526947"', 'Expires': 'Mon, 17 Jul 2023 17:05:53 GMT', 'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT', 'Server': 'ECS (nyb/1D2E)', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-Cache': 'HIT', 'Content-Length': '648')>

<ClientResponse(https://www.example.com) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Age': '314797', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=604800', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Date': 'Mon, 10 Jul 2023 17:05:53 GMT', 'Etag': '"3147526947"', 'Expires': 'Mon, 17 Jul 2023 17:05:53 GMT', 'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT', 'Server': 'ECS (nyb/1DCD)', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-Cache': 'HIT', 'Content-Length': '648')>

<ClientResponse(https://www.example.com) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Age': '592259', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=604800', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Date': 'Mon, 10 Jul 2023 17:05:53 GMT', 'Etag': '"3147526947"', 'Expires': 'Mon, 17 Jul 2023 17:05:53 GMT', 'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT', 'Server': 'ECS (nyb/1D2E)', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-Cache': 'HIT', 'Content-Length': '648')>
```

If I execute `print(await response.text())`, then I see:

```None
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: booboo ,Thanks for the response. does this work for session.post()  call?

Comment: @RameshRaj (1) Yes. and (2)This seems like something you could have tried out yourself rather easily.

Comment: seems like it is not working still i'm seeing the output like this <CIMultiDictProxy('Content-Encoding': 'gzip....., 'Content-Length')>

Comment: @RameshRaj Are you running this from a command prompt? If not, please try it.

Comment: I have added an update, which might be of some help.

Comment: Booboo , got this figured out yesterday and could see the same response from you